# Alert not being hit for responseText from .load()

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why I get the js error

> ResponseText is not defined

in my callback function()

```
        $("#orderListContainer").load("OrderHandler.ashx?action=" + action, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            alert(ResponseText);
        });
```

Comment: Your function seems reasonable. Have you pulled up a Firebug console to see what's going on? My first instinct would be that `$("#orderListContainer")` doesn't exist, so the `.load` is never called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this:

```
alert(ResponseText);
```

should be:

```
alert(responseText);
```

Note the lowercase `r`, as that is the way you named your parameter.

Comment: Explanation: JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @coffee - Nah, just brew up the strong stuff. ;o)

Comment: That reminds me, I have coffee grinds sitting in the other room, totally forgot!